# How to create a pop up for blogger template

Tags: templates, blogger

I have a question, how can I create a costume pop up,so when user visit it show on screen for some minutes.
I have tired creating a pop that show image and text when visitor come.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following

- Create an element with a unique id and place it where you want in
  your template
- Style the element with CSS
- Use JavaScript to hide the element after a desired time

Here is the code

```html
<div id="msg">welcome, I will disappear after 5 sec</div>

<style>
#msg {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 2em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100000;
}
</style>

<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('msg').style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000);
</script>
```